# Make nullable class parameter non nullable in constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Foo {
  int? a
  Foo(this.a);
}
```

Is it possible to have a contructor for this class that will require a non null parameter ?

I tried the following :

```
class Foo {
  int? a
  Foo(this.a);
  Foo.required(int a){
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

But the lint analyser doesn't like it.

Comment: `Foo.required(int this.a);`

Comment: Thank you, why don't you answer instead of commenting ?

Comment: @pskink I am curious also, I find many of answers of yours but you drop them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the named parameter:

```
  class Foo {
   int? a
   Foo({ required this.a});
 }

 final foo1 = Foo(a: null); // ok
 final foo2 = Foo(a: 1); // ok also
```

Comment: The constructor accepts a null parameter, this doesn't answer the question.